# How to go the line that start with given character in Vim?

Tags: vim

Recently I found <kbd>f</kbd> is really handy for me, so I want to know if there a similar command in Vim to go to the line start with given character

something like <kbd>gi</kbd> #go the line started with `i`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is `F` useful - which is like `f` but backwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) by searching.  `/^[your char]` or `?^[your char]` (in reverse)

the **advantage** of this is, it could lead you to the line not displayed in current screen.

**disadvantage** is, you need to give the `char` also pressing several times `n`

** ***if this option works for you, consider to accept answer from sjas or AI***

2) easymotion http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526

```
<leader><leader>j
```

or

```
<leader><leader>k
```

this plugin is very nice, it could navigate to certain position on current screen very fast. apart from the two shortcuts mentioned above, it has

```
<leader><leader>f
<leader><leader>w
<leader><leader>F
...
```

give the plugin a try. you will like it.

**disadvantage**: Hard to handle if the line you want to go is outside current screen.

Answer (score 4):

To jump to the next line beginning with letter L:

```
/^L
```

/ is search forward, ^ is the beginning of a line, then whatever string you want your line to start with.

n for next occurence

N for previous occurence

Answer (score 0):

```
gg/^<character>
```

Should do, it's gg (go to first line) and /^... (simple search).